# (Python 3.8.3) How do I make this string usable with json?

Tags: python, json, string

I'm currently using this code to try to convert a string with "code" and "txt" variables:

```py
    code = full_code()
    specCode = f'{"{0}": "{1}",}'.format(code, txt)
    
    with open(codefile, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(str(specCode), outfile["codes"])
```

`full_code()` is a predefined function.

When I hover over the variable in VS Code, it tells me that the variable is a string. The error, however, tells me that what I'm trying to put into the file is a list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

Again, like I said in my previous question, I am new to Python and don't understand the proper terminology.
I'm sorry for the unclear question, I don't know what else to say. I'm new to both SO and Python, so please, please bear with me. If you need any more information just let me know.

Comment: What are you expecting `json.dump(str(specCode), outfile["codes"])` to do? What is `outfile['codes']`?

Comment: @po.pe I want to put the dictionary into the json file. I don't know the proper way to do this, I'm new to Python as I said. Sorry for any inconsistencies or unclear targets.

Comment: `json.dumps` is converting your string into JSON, it's not writing to your file. Try `outfile.write(json.dumps(specCode))`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It still tells me that the dictionary that should have been converted to a string is a list.

Comment: Can you print `specCode`, Including its type?

Comment: specCode is a different variable each time it is run.
I ran the code and printed it alongside it's type and got the following
 98a3c3208ba6f35033a14a946745616fe51cde5aea25d80c76933fe22931 
 <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the dumps function instead of dump
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.
After feedback from @po.pe I am using `outfile.write(json.dumps(specCode))` already, but the error persists.